# how to create subroutines for add and subtract

Tags: perl, cgi

How to create subroutines for add and subtract in a form where users are ask two enter two different numbers and the sum is the first number they enter plus/subtract the second number they enter.
so far i only have the form:

```
use CGI qw (:standard);
print header;
print start_html;
if (!param)
{ 
    print "<form action='$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME}' method=get>\n",br;
    print "Enter the first number: <input type='text' size='10' name='fnumber'>\n",br;
    print "Enter the second number:<input type='text' size='10' name='snumber'>\n",br;
    print "<input type='radio' name='sum' value='add'>Add\n",br;
    print "<input type='radio' name='sum' value='sub'>Sub\n",br;
    print "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>\n",br;
    print "</form>";
}
print end_html;
```

Answer (score 2):

Subroutines are declared via `sub` like so:

```
sub add {
    my ($x,$y) = @_;

    return $x + $y;
}
```

consider looking at https://learn.perl.org/ or getting a book,
"Learning Perl" is a great.

I personally would not recommend using CGI, as it is ancient, by the way, there are many modern frameworks out there you can use that make life a lot easier. Mojolicious is a good place to start IMO.